# Rubocop: Is there a away to both detecting Rubocop offenses for uncommitted changes and correct them automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I am using [skanev/rubocop.rb](https://gist.github.com/skanev/9d4bec97d5a6825eaaf6) for automatically detecting offenses of uncommitted changes, but it seems like it **can't correct automatically** the offenses it detects.
For the automatic correction of `Rubocop` offences of the entire file, I can use [bbatsov/rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop). But, **I don't want to correct the entire file, but just the uncommitted changes**.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: in bbatsov/rubocop it is not possible, as it doesn't know about what is uncommitted